# How to make this rounding algorithm work with negative numbers?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, rounding

I wrote this simple rounding method in C#, which will round any floating point number (input) to the nearest multiple of any target number (target):

```
float RoundToFloat(float input, float target)
{
    float quotient = input / target;

    if (quotient - Mathf.Floor(quotient) < .5)
    {
        return Mathf.Floor(quotient) * target;
    }
    else
    {
        return Mathf.Ceil(quotient) * target;
    }
}
```

However this seems to break when the input is a negative number. What do I have to do to make it work? I've tried calculating the absolute value of the quotient, and flipping whether I use ceil / floor if the input is negative, but keep getting weird results either way.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is `target`? Also, rounding is available in the `Math` library you're already using.

Comment: @Sach See the first sentence of my post. The built-in "rounding" method simply rounds to the nearest integer, IE a multiple of 1. Say I want it to be a multiple of 3, or 5, or 18.5, or anything. That's what target is for. So for example if I want to round 8.2 to the nearest multiple of 3, the answer would be 9. The question I'm trying to answer, is how to handle negative inputs. So if I wanted -17 to the nearest multiple of 3, I'd want to get -18.

Comment: OK got it, what are the negative numbers this doesn't work for? I tried few like `-5.23f`, `-7.83f`, and `-8.83f` and it seems to work fine. I did use the C# `Math` library though; I don't know what this `Mathf` is.

Comment: @Sach `Mathf` is in the framework.  It's just like `Math`, except it works with floats.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: Grab the `Math.Sign` of the value, do your custom rounding on the absolute value of your input, then multiply the result by the original sign.

Answer (score 0):

Got it ... you need to reverse the applications of `Floor` and `Ceiling` for negative numbers, because the rounding has to be in the 'correct direction' with respect to 0.
`Floor` always goes more negative, while `Ceiling` does the opposite.

You can do this with a "simple" addition to your `if`: an "iff", also known as "Boolean equals".

```
if (quotient - Mathf.Floor(quotient) < .5) ==
   (quotient >= 0) {
```